# Retorno de seleção de radiobutton em C#

Tags: c#, radiobutton

Bom dia.
Tenho um GroupBox que contém 5 RadioButton.
Tenho uma função onde ela recebe o nome do GroupBox e ela retorna 1 se algum RadioButton estiver selecionado e -1 se nenhum RadioButton foi selecionado.
Só que mesmo sem nenhum RadioButton selecionado, ela sempre retorna 1. Gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar a descobrir onde está o erro.
Segue a função.

```
public static int getCheckedRadioButton(Control c)
{
    int i=0;
    try
    {
        Control.ControlCollection cc = c.Controls;
        for (i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
        {
           RadioButton rb = cc[i] as RadioButton;
           if (rb.Checked)
           {
              return i;  //retorna o indice do RadioButton selecionado
           }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        i = -1; // se não tiver nenhum selecionado retorna -1.
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: é Windows Forms? WebForms?

Comment: qual deveria ser o retorno se ele achou um item selecionado retornar 1 e -1 para nenhum selecionado. ou índice do item selecionado igual descrição no código !

Comment: Gente.
Muito obrigado pelas respostas.
Todas as soluções deram certo. Valeu mesmo. José Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código, faltou verificar se o [`Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ettb6e2a(v=vs.110).aspx) é de um determinado tipo, está caindo no valor **-1** todas as vezes por causa de elementos diferentes do [`RadioButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/sefz7fxc(v=vs.110).aspx) que não possui a propriedade `Checked`, ou seja, sempre dando erro: `try` `catch`:

Se dentro desse [`GroupBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox(v=vs.110).aspx) só tiver [`RadioButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/sefz7fxc(v=vs.110).aspx) o código abaixo resolve seu problema retornando o índice do objeto selecionado:

O código abaixo deve resolver isso:

```
public static int GetCheckedRadioButton(Control controls)
{
    int ret = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < controls.Controls.Count && ret == -1; i++)
    {
        if (controls.Controls[i] is RadioButton)
        {
            if (((RadioButton)controls.Controls[i]).Checked)
            {
                ret = i; // seria o índice que precisa.                        
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

---

```
private void BtnVerificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int result = GetCheckedRadioButton(groupBox1);
     /// continuando ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O código sempre retorna 1, quando não está nenhum *RadioButton* `Checked`, porque só há um controle dentro do controle `c`. Se houvesse 2 retornaria 2, etc.

Repare que o `i` é incrementado no ciclo *for* por cada controle em `c`, terminado com um valor igual a `cc.Count`.

Você deve usar uma variável auxiliar para guardar o índice do *RadioButton* `Checked`.

Deve também garantir se o controle é do tipo *RadioButton* antes de verificar se ele está `Checked`. Isso evitará o uso do bloco `try/catch`, que não devem ser utilizados para este tipo de situações.

```
public static int getCheckedRadioButton(Control c)
{
    int index = -1;
    Control.ControlCollection cc = c.Controls;
    for (i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
    {
       if(cc[i] is RadioButton)
       {
           index++;
           RadioButton rb = cc[i] as RadioButton;
           if (rb.Checked)
           {
              return index;  //retorna o indice do RadioButton selecionado
           }
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

É possível simplificar o código de várias formas, entre elas usando `foreach`:

```
public static int getCheckedRadioButton(Control c)
{
    //índice do RadioButton selecionado, -1 indica que não há nenhum.
    int index = -1;
    //Controls implementa a interface IEnumerable, podemos usar foreach
    foreach(var control in c.Controls)
    {
       if(control is RadioButton)//Verifica se é um RadioButton
       {
           //Foi encontrado um RadioButton, incrementa o índice
           index++;
           //faz o cast do control para RadioButton e verifica se está selecionado
           if ((RadioButton)control.Checked)
           {
              return index;  //retorna o índice do RadioButton selecionado
           }
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Utilizando LINQ pode ser ainda mais simplificado e obter directamente uma referência ao *RadioButton* seleccionado:

```
var checkedRadioButton = container.Controls
                             .OfType<RadioButton>()
                             .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

Onde `container` é o controle onde estão os *RadioButton*.
Se não houver nenhum seleccionado `checkedRadioButton` será `null`;

Comment: Eu fiquei também na duvida, sé é pra retornar o indice do elemento ou 1 para algum selecionado e -1 para nenhum selecionado. o AP não interage!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, eu não tive dúvida alguma. O que o AP quer é que retorne o índice do selecionado ou -1 se não houver nenhum. O problema é que o código postado na pergunta está errado pela razão que eu apontei na resposta.

Comment: Então @ramaral o que ficou faltando ele colocar o exemplo desse GroupBox, que na questão ele diz que tem RadioButton se tiver somente radio button não precisa de variavel de controle o proprio `i` por um for simples já responderia a questão dele! mas, é como eu disse não há interação do usuário ...